# How to prevent click through on LottieAnimationView

Tags: java, android, view, onclicklistener, lottie

```
 public void  showProgress(LottieAnimationView lottieview) {
    lottieview.setVisibility(LottieAnimationView.VISIBLE);
    lottieview.bringToFront();
    lottieview.setAnimation(R.raw.wesocialdot);
    lottieview.setAlpha(0.85f);
    lottieview.setRepeatMode(LottieDrawable.REVERSE);
    lottieview.setRepeatCount(9999999);
    lottieview.setEnabled(false);
    lottieview.setClickable(false);
    lottieview.playAnimation();

}
```

I have a method for displaying my LottieView, but the issue i have now...Whenever i click on the LottieAnimationView when it is visible, the click passes onto the views below it.

I have tried

```
lottieview.setEnabled(false);
lottieview.setClickable(false);
```

It is still not working...

Answer (score 1):

```
animationView.isClickable = true
```

You have to make it clickable so that no event can pass through the animation.